# set Boolean to null/Nothing/empty etc in VBA-excel is there any way to do that?

Tags: vba, excel, boolean

I can't find a way to set my var (Boolean) to be empty/Null or other platform then True/False
is there any way to just tell VB that this unit of memory will not be in use ?

Comment: What's your overall goal?

Comment: @user3598756 well, it will be very comfortable for me to have a var that can be set to true/false or null. i earn 3 option and save memory but can it be done?

Comment: Nope, not the Boolean.  It defaults to False https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wts33hb3.aspx

Comment: You could use a `Variant`, which could then be set to `True`, `False` or left `Empty`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Intrinsic types other than `Variant` cannot be set to `Null`.  If you need a nullable value, you need to declare it as `Variant`:

```
Sub Foo()
    Dim x As Variant
    x = Null
    Debug.Print x
End Sub
```

The first downside to this approach is that you'll need to test the variable for `Null` everywhere in your code before trying to assign it to or pass it to any procedure anything requiring a `Boolean`.  Otherwise you'll get an "Invalid use of Null` runtime error.

The second downside is that you're now using a weakly typed variable, which kind of defeats the purpose of declaring it as a `Boolean`.  If you really *need* a type that represents `True`, `False` or `Neither`, one option would be to declare your own Enum and use that:

```
Private Enum Truthiness
    IsTrue
    IsFalse
    IsNeither
End Enum
```

Better would be to restructure your code in a way that ensures that your `Boolean` variables are actually representing a binary condition.

Comment: your last suggestion sound great, 2 question:
I need to declare that in same module can i do it in other module ?
and how i use this new enum ? like that ? Dim test As Truthiness

Comment: the first value of enum is his default value am i get it right?
in this case default will be :"IsTrue"

Comment: @David - If you want one of them to act like a default, assign numbers to them and make the default 0.  For example, `IsNeither = 0`, `IsTrue = 1`, `IsFalse = 2`.

Answer (score 0):

One could utilize the class *default property* and *static module functions* to create some **`Bool` class supporting `False_`, `True_`** (both as singletons), **`Nothing` objects** as well as **`isTrue()`, `isFalse()`** - so the following would work (implementation below):

## Test/Examples

### typical usage examples

```
Sub testBool()
    'New Bool would throw an exception to ensure object equality for False_ and True_ values
    Dim bool As Bool:  Set bool = True_

    'these 2 work only if you are sure its not 'Nothing'! (otherwise throw error):
    If bool Then Debug.Print "1: true!"
    Set bool = False_
    If Not bool Then Debug.Print "2: false!"

    Set bool = Nothing
    If bool Is Nothing Then Debug.Print "3: Nothing!"

    'these 2 work always even if "foo Is Nothing" (unassigned):
    If isFalse(bool) Then Debug.Print "4: isFalse(Nothing) => true!"
    If Not isTrue(bool) Then Debug.Print "5: not isTrue(Nothing) => true!"

    'support for typical Strings, Integers as well:
    If isTrue("1") And Not isTrue("0") Then Debug.Print "6: True ~ 1 and False ~ 0"
    If isTrue("trUe") And Not isTrue("FalsE") Then Debug.Print "7: True ~ UCase('trUe') and False ~ UCase('FalsE')"
End Sub
```

### unit-test-like

```
Sub unittestBool()
    'usage of object False_ and True_ in boolean evaluation (by default property usage)
    Debug.Assert False_ = False   'False_.native is the default property which is "False"
    Debug.Assert True_ = True     'True_.native is the default property whcih is "True"

    'test with Bool variable

    'test for unknown/nothing/null:
    Debug.Assert bool Is Nothing  'unassigned and usable as kind of "Null" as in other languages like Java

    Set bool = False_             'False_ is a singleton (static) function
    Debug.Assert bool = False     'bool.native is the default property which is "False"

    Set bool = True_              'True_ is a singleton (static) function
    Debug.Assert bool = True      'bool.native is the default property which is "True"

    'test True_(Variant) function: with Bool object
    Debug.Assert isTrue(bool)
    Set bool = False_
    Debug.Assert Not isTrue(bool)

    'test False_(Variant) function: with Bool object
    Debug.Assert isFalse(bool)
    Set bool = True_
    Debug.Assert Not isFalse(bool)

    'test True_(Variant) function: with Integer object
    Debug.Assert isTrue(1)
    Debug.Assert Not isTrue(0)

    'test True_(Variant) function: with String object
    Debug.Assert isTrue("true")  'case insensitive
    Debug.Assert isTrue("True")
    Debug.Assert isTrue("trUe")
    Debug.Assert Not isTrue("false")
    Debug.Assert isTrue("1")
    Debug.Assert Not isTrue("0")
End Sub
```

## implementation

### `Bool.cls`

implementation of the `Bool` class (`Bool.cls`):
(the line `Attribute native.VB_UserMemId = 0` is important and one has to **[import it](https://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/694992-how-declare-default-property-class-module) from the `Bool.cls` file(!)** and not just create it!)

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "Bool"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Private val As Boolean

Property Get native() As Boolean
    Attribute native.VB_UserMemId = 0
    native = val
End Property

Property Let native(value As Boolean):  val = value:  End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    If Bool_initialized Then err.raise 1, "Bool", "usage of New Bool forbidden. Use assignment of existing True_ and False_ objects only!"
End Sub
```

### `BoolMod.bas`

implementation of the `BoolMod` module (`BoolMod.bas`):

```
Option Explicit

Private Bool_initCnt As Integer

Public Function Bool_initialized() As Boolean:  Bool_initialized = Bool_initCnt = 2:  End Function


'create singletons that ensure logical equality by object equality using the "is" operator (using the static specifier)

'False_ is the default on construction
Static Function False_() As Bool
    Dim falSing As New Bool:  Set False_ = falSing
    If Bool_initCnt = 0 Then Bool_initCnt = 1:  Debug.Assert True_:  Bool_initCnt = 2  'init True_ object as well
End Function


Static Function True_() As LC_bool
    Dim truSing As New Bool:  Set True_ = truSing
    If Not truSing.native Then truSing.native = True  'after 1st init the native default must be updated
    If Bool_initCnt = 0 Then Bool_initCnt = 1:  Debug.Assert Not False_:  Bool_initCnt = 2 'init False_ object as well
End Function


'isTrue/isFalse(...) supporting Bool, String, Integer, ...

Function isTrue(tst As Variant) As Bool
    Set isTrue = False_
    On Error Resume Next  'e.g. objects can only be converted if they have a default property that can be converted
    If CBool(tst) Then If err.Number = 0 Then Set isTrue = True_
End Function


Function isFalse(tst As Variant) As Bool
    If isTrue(tst) Then Set isFalse = False_ Else Set isFalse = True_
End Function
```